# Ubuntu on an USB Stick - How to see other USB Sticks

Tags: usb, live-usb

I have Ubuntu 19.10 Desktop on a thumb drive with persistence, created by Rufus.

I want to transfer some files from another USB drive (plugged into the same Windows 10 box) or from the Windows 10 `C:\` drive itself - either way would suit my purposes; a `.zip` file and a `.tar` file in the same subdirectory. The `.tar` file is from the Windows 10 bash.

I've not had any luck getting my Linux on the thumb drive to recognize the *other* thumb drive plugged into the same desktop. I've looked under the file/directory structure `/dev` and also `/media` on my Linux/USB thumbdrive/system.

I have also looked under `/mnt/c` and `/mnt` (presumably over on the Windows machine).

How can I resolve this, so I may copy files from USB Flashdrive 'B' to the Ubuntu LiveUSB flash drive 'A'?

Comment: Thanks K7AAY. I've added more information.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu: Have you tried **Disks**? Look there, if you see it, click the little triangle lower left to mount the drive.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll try Disks.